# SliverPersistentHeader in CustomScrollView becomes under the other slivers when scrolling (shown in .gif image). What is wrong and how to fix it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a SliverPersistentHeader widget inside a CustomScrollView.
When I scroll it, it becomes under the other slivers.

[image]

```
[...]
child: Scaffold(
            body: CustomScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              slivers: [
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  delegate: SliverAppBar(expandedHeight: 200),
  pinned: true,
                  );
                _activeScreen(), // This returns a SliverList that contains a Form
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: [...]

class SliverAppBar extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double expandedHeight;

  SliverAppBar({@required this.expandedHeight});

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.black,
                primaryColor,
              ],
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  offset: Offset(0, 0),
                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                  spreadRadius: 5.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text(
            "Sort By Your Taste",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Modak',
              letterSpacing: 1,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
              fontSize: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10) -
                  ((shrinkOffset < expandedHeight - 50
                          ? shrinkOffset
                          : expandedHeight - 50) /
                      10),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
            [...] // Code for that (c) detail
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

What is wrong with it? I think it might have something to do with the Stack widget, but I didn't find any property in it that could fix it.

Please help me, how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the problem was because of the shrinkWrap property that was set to true.

```
[...]
child: Scaffold(
            body: CustomScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true, // <-- Here
[...]
```

I don't remember why I set it to true... But that was the problem, and it has taken so long to me to notice that that was the problem.